# splitting a variable within mako template

Tags: python, mako

The following works on a Python command line

```
CELLULAR='1.2.3.4'
OCTETS=CELLULAR_IP.split('.')
FOURTH_OCTET=OCTETS[3]
T101_IP='10.1.1.'+FOURTH_OCTET
T102_IP='10.1.2.'+FOURTH_OCTET
T103_IP='10.1.3.'+FOURTH_OCTET
T104_IP='10.1.4.'+FOURTH_OCTET
```

But I am having all kinds of trouble doing this in a Mako template.  What I am trying to accomplish is to pass the template an IP address in a variable and to grab the last octet of that IP and use it to create 4 other IPs.  I thought I could put this in a block like this:

```
<%
OCTETS=CELLULAR_IP.split('.')
FOURTH_OCTET=OCTETS[3]
T101_IP='10.1.1.'+FOURTH_OCTET
T102_IP='10.1.2.'+FOURTH_OCTET
T103_IP='10.1.3.'+FOURTH_OCTET
T104_IP='10.1.4.'+FOURTH_OCTET
%>
```

But I get "list index out of range" error.  I think this may also be causing some issues with variable scoping as well which I am trying to wrap my head around.

I also tried to define a function to do this but my limited Python abilities are preventing me for succeeding.

```
def get_octets(ip_string):
   try:
       OCTETS=CELLULAR_IP.split('.')
       return FOURTH_OCTET=OCTETS[3]
   except ValueError:
       return 0
```

Any ideas on what I should be looking at to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try creating a filter to do it? http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html

Comment: Niklas, I looked at filtering but I am not seeing anything that would help here.  I did manage to sort this out using the following but it seems kludgy. `def get_octets(ip_string):
    try:
       return (ip_string).split('.')[3]
    except:
       # if ip_string won’t contain at least three . catch any exception and return -1
       return -1`

Comment: Ok. But you can let the filter take a parameter `ip_string` and write it more clean in the template like `{{CELLULAR|get_octet(1)}}` for example to get the first variable `T101_IP` then you will avoid loose python code in your template and your code will become reusable. If you want to create four other variables based on one, you can use filter and your template code will be clean and free from tightly coupled pure python. It is a good recommendation to avoid mixing python into templates because if you do you cannot reuse the code and it will become difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

This works but seems kludgy.

```
   def get_octets(ip_string):
        try:
           return (ip_string).split('.')[3]
        except:
           # if ip_string won’t contain at least three . catch any exception and return -1
           return -1
```